# CVS - Cleaning up the CVS repository

Tags: cvs, uninstallation, ubuntu-8.04

I just set up CVS on my local machine. But now I need to clean it up and bring it up to a point of the raw CVS installation. I tried searching for `"uninstall cvs on ubuntu"` but did n't find any luck.

Can anyone share his/her views on how to proceed this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case some one bumps into this post, I just marked `cvs` for complete removal from the `Synaptic Package Manager` and deleted the `/var/lib/cvs` folder. No issues so far.

This is a crude way of cleaning the CVS. A better approach which I found is setting up another cvs repository using the same cvs server installation like this:

```
cvs -d /your/new/cvs/repo init
```

Then you can selectively move projects from the old repository to the new one.

Hope this helps.